# Copying from a workbook, paste on the last row + 1 row

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code but it seems that it doesn't work.  What I want is to run the macros on an active workbook (with data):

[image]

Open a database (workbook):

Copy database from range A2 to last row with a value:

[image]

Paste it on the active workbook's last row, below it's last row:

[image]

```
Set targetWorkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook

filter = "All Excel Files (*.csv),*.csv"
caption = "database"
customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(filter, , caption)
Set customerWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set sourceSheet = customerWorkbook.ActiveSheet

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
targetSheet.Range(LastRow + 1, "A").Activate = sourceSheet.Range("A1:T" & LastRow).Value

customerWorkbook.Close
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:
1) you should have source lastrow and target lastrow
2) your 2nd to last statement is wrong.

```
' -- target is activeworksheet
  Set targetworkbook = Application.ActiveWorkbook
  Set targetsheet = targetworkbook.ActiveSheet
  tgtLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
' -- source is csv file
  Filter = "All Excel Files (*.csv),*.csv"
  Caption = "database"
  customerFilename = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filter, , Caption)
  Set customerworkbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(customerFilename)
  Set sourcesheet = customerworkbook.ActiveSheet
  srcLastRow = sourcesheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
'-- now copy
  sourcesheet.Range("A1:T" & srcLastRow).Copy targetsheet.Rows(tgtLastRow + 1)
  customerworkbook.Close
```

Comment: Hi Dcromley,        

I haven't had a chance to look at this on weekends. I'll check this out today and will let you know.

Comment: I've checked both codes from you and Dan. Both were correct, copying the sourcesheet data. I prefer your answer since it copies a specific range (though I still need to change A1 to A2) unlike from Dan that copies all the UsedRange from sourcesheet. Thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

```
'Comment out -

'LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row    
'targetSheet.Range(LastRow + 1, "A").Activate = sourceSheet.Range("A1:T" & LastRow).Value

Dim tr As Range    
Dim sr As Range

Set sr = sourceSheet.UsedRange    
Set tr = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange

sr.Copy Destination:=tr.End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Dan,        

I haven't had a chance to look at this on weekends. I'll check this out today and will let you know.

Comment: I've checked both code from you and dcromley. Both were correct, copying the sourcesheet data. I prefer dcromley's answer since it copies a specific range (though I still need to change A1 to A2). I can still use this on the beginning of my code.
I appreciate your help!